# How android application detects two SD CARDS in a device

Tags: android

If android device has two SD CARDS then how the application detects both SD CARDS in android.For example the device has "left user sdcard" & "right user sdcard". Then  How android supports programmatically
Thanks , Shiv

Comment: Have a look at this ,[ How to detect Dual sd-card][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044545/android-how-to-detect-dual-sd-card

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be just two mount points for two cards in file system. It depends on firmware. The device manufacturer is most likely to define. Though, I have never ever come across any such Android device (actually, no hand held device so far)

Probable mapping:

Your internal flash memory should be: `/mnt/sdcard/`

External cards: `/mnt/sdcard/sdcard1` and `/mnt/sdcard/sdcard2` (or `/mnt/sdcard/sdc1` and `/mnt/sdcard/sdc2`)