# Removable Storage Path in Android Programming

Tags: android, storage, external, sd-card

My question should be kinda simple but I search a lot from the internet, cannot find the answer.

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
is supposed the get the external storage directory (path)
however, most of the phone will return the internal storage because of the manufacturer
"mnt/sdcard"

then how can i get the path of the real removable external storage (SD Card)?
there are lots of answers.

```
mnt/sdcard0/...
mnt/sdcard/sd
mnt/sdcard/ext_sd
mnt/sdcard/external_sd
mnt/sdcard/extSdCard
```

all of above do not work as expected in my Samsung Galaxy S3 (i9300)
a folder just created under /sdcard/ and does not bind(mount, link whatever) to the removable SD Card storage

i found that the path of the sd card in my phone is mnt/extSdCard
and mnt/ext_sd in some of the Sony phone.

that means we cannot have a easy way to get the path rather than "hard coding" it?
if then, do there is a list of the removable storage paths of different phones which different version of android system?

thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044545/android-how-to-detect-dual-sd-card

Comment: hi check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5695129/1168654 read all ans..

Comment: first thanks all for your help.

Comment: actually i have follow cst05001's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0
it works on my S3 but i do not have much devices on my hand so i cannot test the code on the devices.

Comment: Gnathonic's answer also works fine.